# How to use spring-cloud-sleuth to trace spring-security-oauth activities?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to use spring-cloud-sleuth to trace https requests initiated by spring-security-oauth.

But I'm stuck on that the spring-security-oauth filter OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is executed before the spring-cloud-sleuth filter TraceFilter.

Can this be changed so that the spring-cloud-sleuth filter is processed before the spring-security-oauth filter?

Version info:

- spring-boot: 1.3.5
- spring-cloud: Brixton.SR3
- spring-cloud-sleuth: 1.0.3
- spring-security-oauth2: 2.0.9

**Update:**
Based on the suggestion below I could solve the problem by defining my own FilterRegistrationBean as:

```
@Inject
TraceFilter traceFilter;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean myTraceFilter() {
    LOG.info("Register a TraceFilter with HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE");
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(traceFilter, new ServletRegistrationBean[0]);
    filterRegistrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(ASYNC, new DispatcherType[]{ERROR, FORWARD, INCLUDE, REQUEST});
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the TraceFilter yourself and manually provide the order. Just try to put it before the spring security filter. If that works fine you can file a PR / issue describing the whole flow so that we continue the discussion there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Do you mean using a FilterRegistrationBean like:

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean getSleuthTraceFilterRegistrationBean() {

        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        bean.setFilter(new TraceFilter(...));
        bean.setOrder(1);
        bean.addUrlPatterns("/");
        return bean;
    }

But how do I create the TraceFilter, its constructors requires a lot of details that I have no clue of how to fill in :-)

Or have I missed some other simpler way to register the TraceFilter?

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment! Do you mean using a `FilterRegistrationBean`? But how do I create the `TraceFilter`-object? Its constructors requires a lot of details... Or is there a easier way to register the TraceFilter?

Comment: Here you have 2 beans that are responsible for registration - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebAutoConfiguration.java#L98 I'm not sure if it will work properly but you can obviously reuse the bean and try to register it with a higher order in the same way. `TraceFilter` is already a bean - you can just inject it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have updated my question above with a working solution based on your suggestion.